# Bind System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass enums to a WPF combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have my ResourceDictionary declared as:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AutoStart.View"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=mscorlib">


    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="processPrioritiesList" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type system:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And it throws an error saying:

> The name "ProcessPriorityClass" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=mscorlib".

I checked that ProcessPriorityClass is a public member of the System.Diagnostics namespace, but for some reason it's not letting me use the Enum value to be binded to a combobox

How could i accomplish this?

Comment: It's in System.dll, not mscorlib.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong assembly name:

```
xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=System"
```